# Flutter, set android SDK path in ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I was developing flutter apps from around 2 months everything worked perfectly fine, recently I don't remember what I changed in my .bashrc folder in ubuntu since then I am unable to run flutter projects. below is the flutter doctor -v info.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Linux, locale en_IN)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at /home/sai/flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (7 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    • Android SDK at /usr/lib/android-sdk
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/sai/Android/sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/sai/Android/sdk
    ✗ No valid Android SDK platforms found in /usr/lib/android-sdk/platforms. Directory was empty.
    • Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
      visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /home/sai/Softwares/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.2

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Below is my .bashrc code

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/sai/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/home/sai/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin"

export PATH=~/.flutterSetup/bin:$PATH

export ANDROID_HOME=/home/sai/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/sai/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

after replacing the above code with

```
 export PATH="$PATH:/home/sai/flutter/bin"
 export PATH="$PATH:/home/sai/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
 export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin"

 export PATH=~/.flutterSetup/bin:$PATH

 export ANDROID_HOME = "$PATH:/usr/lib/android-sdk"
 export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = "$PATH:/usr/lib/android-sdk"
 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

This error is showed in the android studio terminal, while flutter doctor -v remained the same.

```
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/home/sai/.flutterSetup/bin:/home/sai/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/dart/bin:/home/sai/flutter/bin:/home/sai/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:/usr/lib/dart/bin:/usr/lib/android-sdk': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/home/sai/.flutterSetup/bin:/home/sai/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/dart/bin:/home/sai/flutter/bin:/home/sai/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:/usr/lib/dart/bin:/usr/lib/android-sdk': not a valid identifier
```

Answer (score 1):

shell variable assignment must not have any space around `=` character. From your new `.bashrc` it have space around `=` character. Your old `.bashrc` doesn't, that's why it works fine.